# Don't hide navigation drawer on android 8.0.0

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

Don't hide navigation drawer only android 8.0
On other versions works ok

Android 8.0 [GIF for demonstration](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1t_XliOqKWLZm1MYYstT_mXoo1yAju6_E)
Android 8.1 [GIF for demonstration](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1EE1uFEfab_t9DHknjOs43RARMi8Zxlty)

Comment: please ask your question properly

Comment: first read the guides then try to gain reputation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is solved.
the layouts with the menu were in a different layout, I created a separate layer with the menu and everything worked